# Discord.py - Deleting messages in a channel that do not start with a specific word

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Is it possible to make it so that in a specific channel, any time someone types a message that does not start with a specific word or phrase it gets deleted?

Comment: Please consider coding something yourself first and only asking here if you get errors you can't explain. Looking through the docs would be a good start https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message make sure to read this too if you use the bot class https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with this:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == your_id:
        if not message.content.startswith("your_word"):
            await message.delete()
```

Comment: Note that if he uses the bot class that'll break all the commands in his script, can be easily fixed though https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Comment: @Rémy Noulin For some reason it says that 'Message' object has no attribute 'startswith'. Do you know how I could fix this because I've searched everywhere and I cant find anything?

Comment: my bad, it's `message.content.startswith("your_word")` gonna fix that in the main message, i didn't pay attention sorry